# centus 6 mysql 5.6 always automatically stop, restart mysqld will automatically stop after a while, the wireless cycle

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, centos6

**1.Configuration environment:**

- aliyun
- centos 6.3
- Apache 2.2.4
- mysql 5.6
- php 5.3.3
- WordPress

**2.Problem Description:**
mysql can start normal, but over a period (10 to 30 minutes) ranging from their own stop; SSH command line shown below

```
# /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 183:  9161 Killed                  nohup /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1
```

**mysql stop and then directly start is not enough, will be reported as follows:**

```
# service mysqld restart
Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

**But the first restart httpd, followed by the start mysqld will be able to normal up;**

```
# service mysqld restart
Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
[root@localhost ~]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
[root@localhost ~]# service mysqld restart
Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
```

Mysqld.log ：

```
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [ERROR] Aborting

2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Binlog end
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'FEDERATED'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2017-09-05 23:03:34 10926 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete


2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1600617 in the ib_logfiles!
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.37 started; log sequence number 1600617
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2017-09-05 23:11:21 11670 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.37'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

3.Have tried other ways:
Uninstall and reinstall mysqld, the problem still exists；

Comment: Please post your .cfg/.ini (the complete file).  When Initializing buffer pool fails, it hurts.

Comment: Also, this link may point you towards a solution.
http://www.webtrafficexchange.com/solved-mysql-crash-fatal-error-cannot-allocate-memory-buffer-pool

Comment: Try adding to your .cfg/ini  in [mysqld] section
performance_schema = 0    # for OFF  to try to get past this situation.